# When using a static lib with its own static sub dependencies, do they need linking against even if not utilising any related code?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, linker-errors, static-linking

I have a single project called MyProject.exe which depends on a static lib called MyDep.lib. MyDep.lib contains a function called MyDepFunction() which uses functions in another dependency called SubDep.lib.

As I understand it, if MyDepFunction() is never utilised by any part of MyDep.lib used by MyProject.exe it is sufficient to only link against MyDep.lib. But if MyDepFunction() is utilised by some part of MyDep.lib which is used by MyProject.exe then both MyDep.lib and SubDep.lib must be linked against.

In my case, MyProject.exe doesn't utilise any code in MyDep.lib which calls MyDepFunction() and on machine1 MyProject.exe builds with only MyDep.lib linked. However on machine2 it has compilation errors due to the functions in SubDep.lib used by MyDepFunction() being unresolved externals! So for some reason machine2 requires MyProject.exe to link against SubDep.lib, while machine1 does not.

Is it possible for this to happen without MyDepFunction() being utilised by MyProject.exe? Or is there definitely some difference on the two machines causing one to use it and the other to not?

This is on Windows x64 using MSVC.